# Typescript: is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript

i have this abstract class:

```
export abstract class BaseController {
  private path: string;
  private router: Router;
  constructor() {}
  private initializeRoutes() {}
  public getPath = (): string => {
    return this.path;
  };
  public getRouter = (): Router => {
    return this.router;
  };
}
```

and class:

```
export class Controller {
  private controllers: BaseController[];
  constructor(controllers: BaseController[]) {
    this.controllers = controllers;
  }
  public registerControllersInContainer = () => {
    for (let controller of this.controllers) {
      container.registerSingleton<BaseController>('Controllers', controller);
    }
  };
}
```

usage:

> class test extends BaseController{}
>
> const controllerManager = new Controller([new test()])

but as I'm using typescript when registering my class in the container I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'BaseController' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InjectionToken<BaseController>'.
  Type 'BaseController' is missing the following properties from type 'DelayedConstructor<BaseController>': wrap, reflectMethods, createProxy, createHandlerts(2345)
```

I believe that is why I need to ensure that my controller is not a class:

```
  public registerControllersInContainer = () => {
    for (let controller of this.controllers) {
      container.registerSingleton<BaseController>('Controllers', controller);
    }
  };
```

i don't understand how i can solve this.

Comment: We are missing context of your question.
In pure typescript, this code is correct. What is the framework or library you are using?

Comment: nodejs with typescript

Comment: Please share minimum reproducable example in typescript playground or any other sandbox